# Ajax call to a php script in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I have created a module that is accessible in admin. In that module i have created a form in the .phtml(template) file and after validating it through javascript i want to save the values in the database in products table. I have searched a lot but i could not make a call to the script! Please guide me how can i send the call to php script and get the data successfully, what modules, controllers etc i have to create to do that? Here is my module structure that is making ajax call,

code->local->myspace->mymodule->(model,controllers,etc,helper) and i have included template file in adminhtml->default->default->templates.

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_CoffeeFreak>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Inchoo_CoffeeFreak>
    </modules> 

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <coffefreakblock1>
                <class>Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_Block</class>
            </coffefreakblock1>  
            <coffefreakblock2>
                <class>Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_Block_EditSpecial</class>
            </coffefreakblock2> 
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <coffefreakhelper1>
                <class>Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_Helper</class>
            </coffefreakhelper1>
        </helpers>  
    </global>    






    <admin>
        <routers>

           <samplerouter1>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_AdminControllersHere</module>
                    <frontName>admin</frontName>

                    <modules>
                        <sintax after="Inchoo_CoffeeFreak_AdminControllersHere">Mage_Adminhtml</sintax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
           </samplerouter1>           
        </routers>      
    </admin>





    <adminhtml>


        <menu>
             <mymenu1 translate="title" module="coffefreakhelper1">
                <title>PrintInfo</title>
                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                <children>
                <!-- Note the misleading "module" attribute. 
                    It actualy refers to one of the declared helpers -->

                    <myitem1 translate="title" module="coffefreakhelper1">
                        <title>Add configuration</title>
                        <action>samplerouter1/FreakOut</action>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem1>

                    <myitem2 translate="title" module="coffefreakhelper1">
                        <title>Change configuration</title>
                        <action>samplerouter1/FreakOut2</action>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem2>                    


                </children>
             </mymenu1>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>  
</config>
```

Comment: Can you add your code for config.xml

Comment: you mean code->local->myspace->mymodule->etc->config.xml ????

Comment: Are you trying to add or update product?

Comment: Update. I am updating some attributes when form is being submitted!

Comment: I am just not able to send the values that i get from the form to the php script so that i can save them in database!

Comment: you can probably use magento's built in methods to update attributes/products (you don't need to make your own script for the update itself). let us know what you want to do and we will try and help you

Comment: @R.S: Yes this is an admin module that i have included by myself!

Comment: @pzirkind: I want to pass values from javascript that i have written in a phtml file. How can i use them with built in scripts? and what are they?

Comment: Could you provide an detail example of what your trying to do... because you may be able to do it from within the product manager.

Comment: it depends on what values you want to pass, do you want to update a product? or do you want to update an attribute? etc. Let us know

Comment: In my module admin can add values in the form and on submit the values will be added to the database! i have created the form in .phtml file and validated it there in javascript. now i want to save this data relative to corresponding product!

Comment: In my product I have added attributes like width and height! now i have to add the values that i got from the form into those fields!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish most of what your trying to do within the product admin, but if your want to create your own custom module to save product data then you would need to do something like this

app/code/local/myspace/mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Myspace_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function SaveAction()
    {
        $product_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product_id')
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $product->setName('new_name');
        .....
        $product->save()
    }
}
```

Take a look @ http://www.phpzag.com/create-custom-module-with-custom-database-table/

In your phtml file, you would need to post your ajax action to www.site.com/admin/mymodule/index/save

Comment: The problem is that i have to get the data from a form. So to get data in php from html i need to submit the form and get data through post or through ajax request! and then i have to update product according to that!

Comment: @R.S. answered this part of the question you use this code: $product_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('your_param')

Comment: In my admin, secure keys are turned on! So i have seen in firebug that it sends the request to dashboard as it doesn't identify the key! So what should i do for that?